# Como abrir uma página HTML no browser com o VScode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, navegador-de-internet

Eu preciso abrir uma página no browser com os meus códigos HTML, usando o VSCode.
Entretanto, quando eu faço o F1+tasks: Configure Tasks, não abre o tasks.json.

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode instalar alguma extensão como por exemplo **Live HTML Previewer**

Link da extensão: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hdg.live-html-previewer

Com ela instalada vc pode configurar um atalho para `Open inBrowser`, assim vc vai  poder abrir seu arquivo HTML direto no Browser. No meu caso configurei o atalho conforme imagem <kbd>Ctrl + Q + W</kbd>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** É preciso que vc esteja em um arquivo HTML, vc tb pode clicar com o `botão da direito` e mandar abrir no browser

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Opção 2

Instalar o **Live Server**, com ele vc pode clicar em `Go Live`, ou clicar com o `btn da direita` e mandar abrir no Browser

Link da extensão: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer

**OBS:** Para funcionar vc deve colocar a pasta inteira do projeto dentro  do VS Code, se vc estiver com um arquivo insolado sozinho no VS Code o **GO Live** não vai funcionar!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]